# Does this axiom (a weak form of class valued choice) has a name?

Tags: terminology, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics, axioms

At some point in my work (which has nothing to do with set theoretics foundation) I need to consider the following axiom:

> For any set $X$, any class $V$ with a surjective map $f : V \twoheadrightarrow X$ there exists a small subclass $V' \subset V$
>   such that the restriction of $f$ to $V'$ is already surjective.

(The general framework I'm working in is intuitionist mathematics with a notion of class, and small for a class mean in bijection with a set.)

It can be considered as a weak form of the axiom of choice, as the class valued axiom of choice would be about finding a $V'$ such that the restriction of $f$ is bijective (and in particular $V'$ would be small)

What I want to know is if this axiom appear somewhere in the literature. and especially does it have a name ? As it been studied or used ?

Edit : Eric Wofsey pointed out in the comment that in ZF (with the regularity axioms) this 'axiom' is in fact a theorem. This unfortunately does not apply to the framework I had in mind, but highly suggest that this probably does not have a name or hasn't been studied as an axiom anywhere...

Comment: What is a small subclass? Is it not a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: A small class is a class which is in bijection of a set. It might yields some problem to says that it is a set depending on your foundation: for example if it is ordinary set theory with one Grothendieck universe (where we say sets for element of the universe and class for arbitrary 'set' no necessary in the universe ), you will run into trouble if you ask that for every class $A$, the small class $\{A\}$ is an element of the universe, it will allow to construct the class of all class etc...

Comment: Okay, so I need to ask what is a class? Because I know that a class is a collection of *sets* (or, if you prefer, a "subset" of the universe). Proper classes are never elements of other classes, and in fact that is a good way to distinguish sets from classes. Sets are classes which are elements of other classes. So if $A$ is a proper class, $\{A\}$ is not anything as far as theory goes, it is singleton in the meta-theory, sure. But if in the meta-theory your universe is countable, what does it mean to have a bijection with a set? So I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: In the framework of ZF, this (stated as a theorem schema) follows from Foundation by [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick) (and does not involve Choice at all).

Comment: Ok if you are assuming that proper class cannot be element of other class then you are ok. But I prefer to consider that my 'class' behave like sets (for exemple I want to be able to talk about the class of functions between two given class) which is not possible if class cannot be element of class. So I can use either ordinary set theory + one Grothendieck universe as I said in my previous comment, or take ordinary set theory (calling the object class instead of set) with one additional predicate that distinguishes 'set' from 'class' + a few additional axioms...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't fully understand what *you* mean by class.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I shouldn't have use the word 'class' at all. I don't mean the 'meta' notion (a familly of sets that can be defined by a formula). I assume that I am working in a framework where I have a notion of class satisfying some axioms (so the question " what is a class" is basically the same thing as "what is a set" when working with ZF) and I don't really care on whether or not class can be element of class... In my mind this distinction was irrelevant for the question, But Eric Wofsey comments showed me that it is...

Comment: I think this is a variation of (algebraic set theory version of) the axiom of collection. See [Joyal and Moerdijk, _Algebraic set theory_, Ch. I, §1].

Comment: @ZhenLin : thank you, I just check the book and this is indeed exactly the "collection axiom" when we write it in terms of categorical logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In weak set theories, using classical logic and interpreting
"small subclass" as "set", this principle amounts to an
alternative formulation of the collection axiom. For example, in
Zermelo set theory or even much weaker theories, even without the
power set axiom, this principle is equivalent to the collection
axiom scheme.

**Collection:** If $X$ is a set and $\forall a\in X\exists b\
\varphi(a,b)$, then there is a set $Y$ such that $\forall a\in
X\exists b\in Y\ \varphi(a,b)$.

One can replace the talk of a formula $\varphi(a,b)$ with
membership in a class of pairs.

If we have collection, then suppose we have a class surjective
function $f:V\to X$ as in your case. Since for every $a\in
X\exists b\ f(b)=a$, by collection we can find a set $Y$ such that
for every $a\in X\exists b\in Y\ f(b)=a$, and so $f\upharpoonright
Y:Y\to X$ is already surjective, as desired.

Conversely, if your axiom holds and we have a formula
$\varphi(a,b)$ for an instance of collection, so that $\forall
a\in X\exists b\ \varphi(a,b)$, then let $f(a,b)=a$, provided that
$\varphi(a,b)$, so that $f$ is surjective from the class
$\{(a,b)\mid \varphi(a,b)\}$ to $X$. Under your axiom, there is a
set $Y$ such that $f\upharpoonright Y:Y\to X$ is already
surjective. In this case, the projection of $Y$ onto the second
coordinate, that is, the set $B=\{b\mid \exists a\ (a,b)\in Y\}$
is a set, and the surjectivity of the restriction amounts to
$\forall a\in X\exists b\in B\ \varphi(a,b)$, thus verifying the
desired instance of collection.

This argument doesn't seem to need much at all in the background
set theory, although I am not sure what the effects would be
without classical logic.

Comment: Thank you, together with Zhen lin comment on the "categorical version" of this axiom it gives me exactly what I needed, and it indeed apply largely independently of the background theory.